# Ruby Regex Gsub when does not match

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I want to gsub all characters in a string that are not letters and replace with '#'. I think I need a regular expression that goes something like, "gsub() when this regex does not match."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look ma, no regex...

```
str.tr( '^A-Za-z', '#' )
```

Comment: `^A-Za-z` is totally regex :P

Answer (score 9):

```
str.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/, '#')
```

The **^** means doesn't match

Comment: Thanks a million!

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can use the character class negation:

`"aBc$%^".gsub(/[^A-Za-z]/, '#') => "aBc###"`

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://codepad.org/7rnqOVBT) on Codepad:

```
puts "kjhdfuy37685682#$$%@dfjahf".gsub(/[^a-z]/i, '#')
```

Answer (score 1):

***Words*** do count

**all** character **s** ... replace with '#' `str.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]+/, '#')`

**each** character ... replace with '#' `str.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/, '#')`